# How to load images after page loaded?

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    var id = 'i1';
                    var image = new Image();
                    image.src = 'http://url_to_my_image';
                    image.onload = function(){
                        $('#m' + id).attr('src',image.src);
                        $('#m' + id).show();
                    };
                  });

            </script>
            <ul style="list-style: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
                <li id="i1" style="display: inline;">
                    <div style="background-color: #bbb; width:768px;height:1024px;"><div style="margin-top:505px; margin-left: 370px; font-size: 24px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #333;">Load...</div></div>
                    <img src="" id="#mi1" style="display: hidden;" />
                </li>
            </ul>
```

But this not work. I want to display all empty pages with text "Loading..." and after load image page insert it to the relevant img element.

Sorry for my terrible english...

Comment: I would suggest using lowsrc attribute in your html if the image is not dynamically loaded : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_lowsrc.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#m"+id).load("//your link");
```

You can read more on this on: [api.jquery.com/load/](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 1):

The `display: hidden` set on your `<img>` element should be `display: none`.  Also, bear in mind that users visiting your page with JavaScript disabled will never see the image, only the permanent loading message.  You should use a gracefully degrading solution instead.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [link](http://aadhir.com/?p=12)

This plugin loads images / background url after the DOM load event and window load event are triggered.

Initially the src attribute of the img tag will be set to empty. And the html should contain a data attribute which will contain the image path. The plugin will take care of the rest of things.

After image loads, the below code will be executed. All these are handled by the plugin

```
$('img').attr('src', < data URL with the img path > )
```