# Disable loading images while the web-page is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

Most of my website visitors are using limited bandwidth & slow internet.
so I'm trying to reduce the load time and save their bandwidth by disable loading images & background images while the web-page is loading, then give an option to load the web-page's images when click "show images" button.

i'm thinking of some thing like lazy load but with on-click action.

I appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Use `data-src` attribute instead of `src` attribute and on change, setthe `data-src` value to `src` attribute.

Comment: Do you need Placeholders? and what about css background images?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/fx3h4ug8/

Comment: Background images may be tricky to do if they're specified in a separate CSS file.

Comment: Take a look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062935/how-to-load-images-after-page-loaded

Answer (score 2):

One idea:

-Keep empty src attributes for images

-Store img urls on an attribute (you can call it data-src)

-Use Jquery to replace src with data-src value when page is loaded or when User clicks "show images"

Answer (score 1):

I think there are 2 different scenarios:

**IMG-TAGS**

HTML:

```
<img src="" data-load="http://imagesource" alt="">
```

jQuery:

```
$('img[data-load]').each(function(){        
  $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('load'));
});
```

**BACKGROUND-IMAGES**

HTML:

```
<div class="background-placeholder"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.background-placeholder {
  background-color:#fff;
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
}

.show-bg1 {
  background-image:url('http://imagesource');
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.background-placeholder').addClass('show-bg1');
```

CSS background-images are **not loaded** when **a class isn't used** (Same on hover etc.) 
It's not the most efficient way to do this, but it could give you an idea on how its done. 
Maybe you could store css-classes with the right background images also in data-attributes and loop through.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tjqwpea0/)

Answer (score 0):

The nested functions look a bit yucky, but here's a jQuery solution to your problem, using the method mentioned above.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ // wait until the document is loaded
  $('#loadimages').click(function(){ // before registering the event handler  
    $('img[data-src]').each(function(){ // and for each image with a data-src attribute     
      $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('src')) // copy it's contents into the src attribute
    })
  })
})
```

```css
img[data-src]{
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
}

img[data-src][src=""]::after {
  content: 'Placeholder';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/200/400"/> 
<img src="" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/200/400"/>
<img src="" data-src="http://lorempixel.com/200/400"/>
<button id="loadimages">Load Images</button>
```