# Optimize Image Loading for Large Images

Tags: jquery, html, css

In developing my site, I have ran into an issue with my hero image of sorts. Being a larger image with a 1920x1080 resolution JPEG at 1.2 MB, the image has a delay in loading with the website leaving the background color to show for a split second before loading in. I really need to get rid of this snap loading, and am wondering how I can do it. I am a bit novice in JQuery but have some knowledge, can I use it to delay the page load until the image is fully loaded? Maybe a full body page loader waiting until the page has loaded fully would be good. Up for anything really.

Comment: You could definitely use a loading screen to accomplish that. [Here is an example from 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062935/how-to-load-images-after-page-loaded) You can also use progressive jpeg to help, because they fade in when loading, rather than loading from top-down.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will surly look into either option and get back to you on whether they work or not.

Comment: Through your link I was able to find the appropriate answer to my problems with $(window).on('load', function() {